# How to determine whether an object can be convert to meaningful string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to determine whether the ToString() method of an object will return a meaningful string instead of its class name. For example, bool, int, float, Enum, etc. returns meaningful string, instead an instance of ArrayList will return "System.Collections.ArrayList". If there a simple way to archive that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Wayne

Comment: The real question is if it can be determined if the class (or base class if inherited) has its own implementation of the `ToString()` method, and not just inherits form the implementation in `Object`.

Comment: Yes, I haven't realize that. Once realized, the solution is easy to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could compare `object.ToString()` with `object.GetType().ToString()` ?

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Heh, +1. Actually that's the most straightforward solution :-)

Comment: Well, object.GetType().ToString() ;-)

Comment: Great suggestion (+1). Only it should be to compare `object.ToString()` with `object.GetType().ToString()` .

Comment: That's the simplest and good enough solution I think. thanks Dan.

Comment: Crikey, ramping up the rep Dan on this trivial one. ;-) Nice!

Comment: The simplest are always the best +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to check if class of object overrides toString. Like this

```
if (obj.GetType().GetMethod("toString",
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) != null)
{
    // do smth
}
```

Update - see if any base class has toString implementation that is not from Object.

```
        MethodInfo pi = null;
        Type t = obj.GetType(0;
        while (t != typeof(object) && pi == null)
        {
            pi = t.GetMethod("toString",
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.Public | 
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            t = t.BaseType;
        }

        if (pi != null)
        {
            // do smth
        }
```

Comment: If the tested object inherits from a type which does override ToString() you would get incorrect results. To prevent this you would have to recursively step through the supertypes as well until you are arrived at Object.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `if (obj.GetType().GetMethod("toString") == typeof(Object).GetMethod("toString") ) { ... }` ?

Comment: The problem is that Object does not have "Meaningful" implementation of toString, and some other standart base classes, such as Component, also has toString implementation which is not meaningful.

Comment: I think the your ideas is similiar to Dan's. Thought I could only pick one as the answer.Thanks.